# ffmpeg merge images with first image duration

Tags: image, merge, ffmpeg

I'm try to merge some images in a mp4 with ffmpeg.
I do it with:

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -i %06d.jpg -s 480x360 -vcodec libx264 /output.mp4
```

The first image must have duration of 3 seconds and the others must have framerate of 25.

I know I can do this for set the duration of an image:

```
-loop 1 -t 3 -i 000000.jpg-s 480x360 -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```

But how can I merge the two things?? The first image of 3 seconds and the others image with 25 fps in one mp4 output??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create two individual video files separately and join them after. You can try the `concat` methods available [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate). Following is a simple `concat` using `filter_complex`

```
ffmpeg -i input_video1 -i input_video2 -filter_complex "
[0:0][0:1][1:0][1:1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map [outv] -map [outa] -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

If the images are not in the same dimensions you may need to [`scale`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#scale-1) them. Two videos may have different [sar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio) values and need to adjust them accordingly using [`setsar`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#setdar_002c-setsar). Also feel free to change the video and audio [codecs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html) depending on your need of output format as you need to re-encode this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `ImageMagick` like this, if you have three files called `red.png`, `green.png` and `blue.png`:

```
convert -delay 300 red.png -delay 40 green.png blue.png anim.mp4
```

I'll show it as an animated GIF below, by changing the `mp4` to `gif`

[image]

The parameter `-delay` is a *setting* so it persists until changed, so it aplies to both `green.png` and `blue.png`.

You would probably change `green.png` and `blue.png` to `*.jpg`.

`ImageMagick` is pre-installed on most Linux distros, and available for OSX (ideally via `homebrew`) and also for Windows.

If you want to use `ffmpeg`, I think you have a couple of possibilities

a) specify the frame rate as 25 fps but repeat the first frame 75 times like this:

```
(for i in {1..75}; do printf "file 'red.png'\n"; done; printf "file '%s'\n" *.jpg) > list.txt
ffmpeg -r 25 -f concat -i list.txt -s 480x360 -vcodec libx264  anim.mp4
```

b) make a 3 second mp4 and another mp4 with 25 fps and concatenate them

Comment: I must use ffmpeg because I do it on Android and ImageMagick on it not work well.  Ok the the ffmpeg solution is  but how con I concatenate the two mp4?? Thanks

Comment: [FFmpeg concat](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) is there. Have you tried them? Hopefully `filter_complex` concatenation will work for you.